# alchemy api always says "totalTransactions: 730" even after just starting

Tags: alchemyapi

I just today got an api key, and even after just a few loads of the sample queries with my key, i get intermittent errors saying that i've exceeded my daily 1000 transactions, and the transactions count is always 730.

Is this just a bug? or does this not mean what I think it means?

**Edit:** the conclusion is that there is an internal "cost" of running each query. that totalTransactions number refers to the internal costing, not my number of API calls made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction load for the AlchemyData News service is quite a bit higher than the other Alchemy services. Using the basic NLP services will generally cost you one transaction per call, and the image services cost four transactions per call. With the News service, because data storage and content curation is already handled for you, there are a lot more costs bundled in. You can reduce the number of transactions greatly by shortening the time window you are querying over.

Comment: so, If i want to simply list articles written about a particular keyword for a 30 day window, my 1 API query is actually being costed at hundreds of transactions?

Comment: Yes, it's the 30 day window that's costing so much. The value in the service doesn't come from doing simple keyword searches and returning articles. There are other APIs that can do that for less. With the AlchemyData News service, there is a whole slew of metadata that can be included in your queries and results that you won't find elsewhere. This includes disambiguated entities, subject-object-verb relations, sentiment, etc. If you don't need that additional level of understanding it may not be the right service for your application.

Comment: Ya. that may be the case, my application is already built atop an RDF db, and already has the ability to run sentiment analysis over content, so in theory I could manually do a lot of this, but for a minute i thought it would allow me to skip over a bunch of work and just get the end result. i guess i'll go look for something else that makes sense for my app. thanks for your insights